Is it possible to debug java and C++ in mixed mode?
I would like to know if it is possible to debug a Java program in which some methods are implemented using JNI in C++ in Visual Studio Code. I want to use only the Java Debug Extension and the C/C++ Extension from Microsoft. I have searched Google for information regarding this but haven't found anything helpful. My requirement specifically pertains to debugging JavaCard applets, but initially, I would like to understand how to debug standard Java programs that utilize JNI. I have no clue how I can utilize both extensions concurrently to achieve my goal. If someone has tried out something similar or has any idea how I can do this, please help.

Well, I don't know if this will give you any hints, but for Visual Studio (not VS Code), all you have to do is load the JNI project in Visual Studio, go to the Debug window, start the Java program, and "Debug / Attach" to the javaw.exe process that your Java app is associated with.  Then you put a breakpoint in the JNI code and wait for the breakpoint to occur.  Whether this is similar to how you would use Visual Studio Code, you will have to determine this (since I don't use VS Code for development of Java / JNI apps).

Is it possible to debug java and C++ in mixed mode? -- So in a nutshell, it is possible.  The issue is whether you have the tools to do so (again, Visual Studio allows this easily).

I specifically want to know if this works in VS Code (not Visual Studio or any other IDE). I have some JavaCard extensions that work only in VS Code.

As I mentioned I gave you hints, and for you to see if you have anything that mimics the "Attach to Process" debug option.  Most debuggers I know do have this -- it doesn't matter if it's JNI or even pure C++, a good debugger should allow you to attach to a running process, and in this case, the running process is javaw.exe.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_multitarget-debugging                           https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configuration-options

Not exactly what you are looking for, but you can apply the same approach: https://youtu.be/8Cjeq4l5COU
